# Netcat will not send messages through UDP connection between Socket PDU blocks in GNU Radio Companion

Tags: udp, netcat, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I am fairly new to Linux and GNU Radio.

I am trying to use GNU Radio to process information. To pass information into GNU Radio, I was planning on using the Socket PDU blocks to pass in information through a socket. To test out the connection I placed 2 Socket PDU blocks in GNU Radio Companion and connected them together, then I used netcat to send and receive messages and files.

I was able to get the connection to work when I had both Socket PDU blocks to TCP server. The sending block was set to port 52001 and the receiving block to 52002. In one terminal I typed:

```
nc localhost 52002
```

In a second terminal I typed:

```
nc localhost 52001
```

After that, any messages I typed in the second terminal appeared in the first.

I tried to do the same thing with setting the Socket PDU blocks to UDP Server and using the commands:

```
nc -u localhost 52002
nc -u localhost 52001
```

But nothing I typed in the second terminal would appear in the first.

What am I missing here? Does netcat just not work with this kind of stuff, or am I forgetting a step? With being new to Linux, GNU Radio and network protocols, I don't even know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to go to the receiving terminal and press enter. This will send an empty UDP packet to the server and tell it about the existence of this terminal/socket.

Just

```
nc -u localhost 52001
```

doesn't do anything as UDP has no connection setup.